# The user that asked the question, fixed the final correct solution on the answer, but I rejected it because of lack of info

Tags: discussion

Today I rejected this review

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1148728

Its seems that the already accepted answer was radically changed because the code was changed.

However the user `lemzwerg` that made the code change (that I rejected) is the one that asked the question, accepted the answer, and was trying to help the community by placing the final code that worked for him.

If I know that the user that make the edit was the one that made the question I would have decided differently. Now the user `lemzwerg` has not only lost the changes, but has also received a declined flag due to radical change, but actually was trying to help us by giving us the final code.

Is there a way to specially handle those cases by adding to the comment an extra note or something to the effect that the one who wrote the question and accepted the answer, actually made this correction?

Comment: I was just thinking about this today. I hate it when I am looking for help on a subject and find what seems to be a person asking the same question that I have. There's some discussion, some suggestions, then the OP says, "I FIXED IT!" and the thread dies. It makes me want to murder. So, how to avoid that here on SO? I was thinking that you could accept the answer that guided you to the final solution, add a new answer to your own question with your final solution, then edit a link to your final solution answer into your question.